# Elements chosen have same value but different id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I choose to run the same function with different parameters according to the id?

In the JQuery, the input buttons with `value="+"` is chosen, then I want to determine what is their id, and then call the javascript function with different parameters.

For example, button with `id="Add_1"` is chosen, then the function called is `getData(0);`

Here is the html (extract)

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="../css/coin_convert.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="coin_convert.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="form">
<form name="coins">
<input type="button" value="+" id="Add_1" />
<input type="button" value="+" id="Add_2"/>
<input type="button" value="+" id="Add_3"/>
<input type="button" value="+" id="Add_4"/>
</form>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Here is the JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("[value='+']").on("click", function() {
      if($("[value='+']").is("Add_1")){
        getData(0);
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the JavaScript function to be called

```
function getData(n){
    var coin = new Array(4);
    switch (n){
        case 0:
            coin[n]=document.getElementById('coin_dragon').value;
            break;
        case 1:
            coin[n]=document.getElementById('coin_sky').value;
            break;
        case 2:
            coin[n]=document.getElementById('coin_special').value;
            break;
        case 3:
            coin[n]=document.getElementById('coin_legend').value;
            break;          
    }
    addition(coin[n]);

}
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.attr('id')` to find the ID attribute.

In order to have this run for each element that has the associated ID, you would need to run a loop that uses an index, and gets the data based off of that index:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[value='+']").each(function(index) {
    $(this).click(function() {
      if ($(this).attr('id') == 'Add_' + (index + 1)) {
        getData(index);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

In this example, whenever an element with both a value of `+` and an ID that starts with `Add_` is clicked, `getData()` will trigger, passing through one less than the the number in the element's ID. Clicking an element with an ID that doesn't start with `Add_` will not trigger `getData()`.

I've created a working fiddle showcasing this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/e17uzhtd/).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You use .attr('id') to get the id of an element

```
if($("[value='+']").attr('id')== 'Add_1'){
    getData(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest some new ideas based on the code that you've provided:

getData just appears to call 'addition(value)' depending on the button that was clicked.  I've refactored the code down contain a data attribute on each button and then just pass that along.

See this fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/88z1e4yu/

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#form-coin > input").on("click", function() {
      getData($(this).data('coin'));
    });
});

function getData(coin){
  alert(coin);
  addition(document.getElementById(coin).value);
}
```

Comment: what if a have different button that serves different purpose?

Comment: Just add a more specific selector to the query/button.  For example, add a class "add-btn" to each input that you wish and then change the click function to target: $('#form-coin input.add-btn").on("click", ...

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's [`.is()` function](https://api.jquery.com/is/) expects the passed parameter to be a selector. As such, your `is()` condition should check for `"#Add_1"`, not `"Add_1"`

```
if($("[value='+']").is("#Add_1")){
```

---

You could alternately get them all by using the [Attribute Starts With Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
$('[id^="Add_"]'))
```

And later check the number with the [Attribute Ends With Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)

```
$('[id$="_1"]'))
```